# Making a function available to all models

Tags: python, django, model

I have the following function in one of my models

```
def get_fields(self):
   return[(field.name, field.value_to_string(self)) for field in MusicPack._meta.fields]
```

Which helps me iterate over all the fields of a model and display them into a template. How would I implement this to all my models without replicating the two lines in every model in my database?

Would I just make a superclass that contain the function for all models and then have all my models children of it?

template.html

```
<div id = "subtemplate">
    <ul>
    {% for model in object_list %}
        <div class = modeldiv>
        {% for name,value in model.get_fields %}
            <li>
            {% if value %}
            {{ name|capfirst }} : {{ value }}
            {% endif %}
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
            {% empty %}
            <li> No objects created yet. </li>
            {% endfor %}
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: it depends, but `from my_module import get_fields` may work be in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Mixins.

Example

```
class Mixin(object):
    def get_fields(self):
        return[(field.name, field.value_to_string(self)) for field in self.__class__._meta.fields]

class A(models.Model, Mixin):
    ...

class B(models.Model, Mixin):
    ...
```

Comment: After a quick google search on the topic, that is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you

Comment: @tama If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @Maxime Lorant, thanks for that! I'm still kind of new to the site. Cheers

Comment: @tama No problem, we have all been there before :)

Answer (score 0):

Putting that method in a base class is certainly one way to do it. Another approach is to have it be a generic utility function in some utility module that prints all fields in an object, which you  can call before rendering your template.

```
from myproject.utilities import get_fields

...

return render_template("template.html", get_fields(model))
```

Yet a third approach is to write a class decorator which provides this functionality to a class:

```
class with_get_fields(cls):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) 

    def get_fields():
         return [(field.name, field.value_to_string(self)) for field in cls.fields]
```

and then apply it to any model class that you wish to have this functionality

```
@with_get_fields
class model():

       def __init___(self):
           ...
```